# Equation without any symbols

Tags: math-mode, symbols, equations

I got a strange Problem while writing on my bachelor thesis. 
If i set up a equation the result is displayed without any mathematic symbols. 
For example:

```
\begin{equation}        
    \frac{2 + dc}{9}
\end{equation}
```

becomes 
[image: Equation without +]

"=" does also not work.
These are the packages i've used in this work, maybe there is one which breaks the equation stuff.

Would be cool if someone could help me.

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Kodierung, Zeichensatz
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} %Deutsche Sonderzeichen/Umlaute
\usepackage{tocloft} %Kontrolle über alle automatischen Listen
\usepackage{geometry} %Ermöglicht das erweiterte Verändern der Dokumentgeometrie
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Erweiterte Formattierungsmöglichkeiten der Kopf- und Fusszeilen


\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{ifthen} % ermöglicht If Bedingungen (\ifthenelse{}{}{})
\usepackage{xstring} % Auswerten und Manipulieren von Strings
\usepackage{tikz} %Erstellen und Manipulation von Grafiken, sowie Logische Operatoren

\usepackage{fourier} %Erweiterter Mathematischer Zeichensatz, nutzt Adobe Utopia Font
\usetikzlibrary{chains,shapes.arrows,fit} %Tikzlibrary zum erstellen der notwendigen Grafiken


\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx} %SI-Einheiten
\usepackage{xfrac}



%%% Texteigenschaften
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} %Zeilenabstand
\usepackage{microtype} %Mikrotypographischer Zeicheneigenschaften
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}%Schriftart Times Roman
\usepackage{courier}%Schriftart Times Roman
\usepackage{parskip}

%%% Literaturverzeichnis und Zitate
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
%\usepackage[natbib=true]{biblatex}

%%% Tabellenformattierung
\usepackage{longtable,ragged2e} %Erlaubt Tabellen über den Zeilenrand zu ragen
\usepackage{multirow}  %Verbinden mehrerer Zeilen in Tabellen   
\usepackage{array} %Erweiterung der Tabellen und Array Umgebung 
\usepackage{booktabs} %Verbesserung der Tabellenerstellung

%%% Objekteigenschaften
\usepackage{float}  %Verbesserte Eigenschaften von float-Objekten
\usepackage{pst-all} %PostScript macros
\usepackage{graphicx} %Erweiterte Grafikeigenschaften
\usepackage[margin=0pt,font={small,it,onehalfspacing,sf},labelsep=colon,parskip=6pt]{caption} % Formattierung der Objektcaptions

%%% Zusatzpakete
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym} % Verwalten und Erstellen eines Kurzzeichenverzeichnises
\usepackage[]{pdfpages} % Erlaubt das Einbinden von PDF-Dateien
\usepackage{etex} %Erweitert die bereitgestellten Packageregister
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) What do you compile your document with?

Comment: Could you provide a complete [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?

Comment: In addition to @ClaudioFiandrino, the above should not be a part of a minimal working example. There are too many packages included. Start by removing one, recompile, if the output is the same, then proceed removing packages. In many cases this method ends up reveling the real culprit. So it is a vital debugging technique to learn

Comment: Im compiling with texpad. But i already found the issue on My own. Removing The Mathpmx package does the Trick. But it would be interesting why this package breaks the Symbols..

Comment: Your code contains no documentclass...

Answer (score 2):

You're loading both `fourier` and `mathptmx`; the package `fourier` changes many correspondences between symbols and the way they're input, because its fonts are encoded differently from the standard. The `mathptmx` package assumes the math symbols are in their standard slots, so chaos ensues.

If you want Times New Roman as your main font, then remove the call to `fourier` and  use `mathptmx` or, better,

```
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
```